# Make list of most recurring words in data frame, match and input suggestion(s) column

Tags: r, text-mining

I have a very huge .csv document (hard to put a similar example) will try to explain here:

I need to use R Studio to look for the most recurring words in all of the columns, after that I want to match the list of recurring words in the category comparing them and choosing the match(es) (even if it matches only part of the category) and then input the matched word(s) in the same row but new column I'm calling "suggested_edit"

Here's a brief example before I state what codes I tried:

```
Category       ID       Place1    Place2  **suggested_edit**(i need to add this)

abc-cba bac     123321      bac       N/A   bac   
adb- bac bad    213241      N/A       bac   bac  
bdl- bdc bdd    613251      N/A       N/A   N/A
ajk- bcd dcx    613251      ddd       bcd   ddd, bcd
abc - bdd fcl   776445      trf       fss   trf, fss
abc - bnc vcc   767544      vcc       qap   vcc
```

and the table is pretty big,

What i tried is this:

```
df<- df[order(dfFT$Place1), ]

df$rank <- rank(df$Place1, ties.method = "min")

df <- df[order(df$rank, decreasing = FALSE), ]

install.packages("tm")
```

tried to use the `findFreqTerms()` command but its returning an error message: no applicable method for 'findMostFreqTerms' applied to an object of class "data.frame"

Comment: First, you will need to apply whatever function you use only on the column of the `data.frame` that includes your words, e.g., `df$Category`, not the whole `data.frame`. Could you please provide an example of your expected output in the suggested edit column. I have an idea what you want and I think it can be solved easily, e.g., with packages `tm` or `text2vec`, but I do not fully understand what your final output should be.

Comment: Further question, what is the meaning of hyphens in your words. Is "abc-cba" one word or two? Just to know where to split up tokens... I am asking because you also have "adb-" in your data without a second phrase attached.

Comment: The hyphens are separators, they are part of the format that the category is written in, i wrote them here just to make sure  they wont cause an issue when I run any suggested code,
That said I want to provide suggested_edit based on category, place 1 and place 2, hopefully this helped, ready to answer anything new. Thanks

Comment: The hyphens are not a problem, just wanted to know how to treat them. But again, could you please fill the colulmn "suggested edit" in your example. This will make it much easier to understand what you want.

Comment: done, as you can see it was hard for me to explain it properly, but I hope this helps, in case either place 1 or place 2 match category then I want the matching and in case both do not match category then it can either be place 1 or place 2 and the third condition is if both place 1 and place 2 re N/A then I want it to say N/A (the last option is a rare thing in my data frame so not mandatory)

Comment: I still do not fully understand, e.g., in the following line `ajk- bcd dcx    613251      ddd       bcd   ddd, bcd`  the pattern `ddd` is not matched in the category column (in none of the rows) but appears in the suggested edit. Is this a desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

As per my last comment I am not sure if I understood you correctly, so I have updated you example as I understand it and have changed the "Place2" in the first row to "abc", so that there are two patterns matched. On this basis I have provided an answer based on `str_extract` from `stringi` package. I hope this is what you were looking for. I have imported your data as `matrix` since you have not provided a reproducible example. As long as the specified columns are of type `character` the solution should also work for `data.frame` (hopefully, not tested).

```
cat("
Category       ID       Place1    Place2  **suggested_edit**

abc-cba bac     123321      bac       abc   bac   
adb- bac bad    213241      N/A       bac   bac  
bdl- bdc bdd    613251      N/A       N/A   N/A
ajk- bcd dcx    613251      ddd       bcd   ddd, bcd
abc - bdd fcl   776445      trf       fss   trf, fss
abc - bnc vcc   767544      vcc       qap   vcc", file = "tmp.txt")
dat <- read.csv("tmp.txt", sep = "\n")
unlink("tmp.txt")

head <- unlist(strsplit(gsub("\\.+", "#", names(dat)), "#"))
dat <- unname(dat)
dat <- t(apply(dat, 1, function(x) {unlist(strsplit(x, "\\s{2,}"))}))
colnames(dat) <- head
dat[,"suggested_edit"] <- NA
dat
# dat[ dat == "N/A"] <- NA
# Category        ID       Place1 Place2 suggested_edit
# [1,] "abc-cba bac"   "123321" "bac"  NA     NA            
# [2,] "adb- bac bad"  "213241" NA     "bac"  NA            
# [3,] "bdl- bdc bdd"  "613251" NA     NA     NA            
# [4,] "ajk- bcd dcx"  "613251" "ddd"  "bcd"  NA            
# [5,] "abc - bdd fcl" "776445" "trf"  "fss"  NA            
# [6,] "abc - bnc vcc" "767544" "vcc"  "qap"  NA  

library(stringi)
check_edit <- function(mymatrix, categorycolumn, checkcolumns, suggestioncolumn) {

  edit <- t(apply(mymatrix, 1, function(x) {
               unlist(stri_extract_all_fixed(x[categorycolumn], x[checkcolumns]))
            }))

  mymatrix[, suggestioncolumn ] <- apply(edit, 1, function(x) paste(x[ !is.na(x)], collapse = ", "))
  return(mymatrix)
}

check_edit(dat, "Category", c("Place1", "Place2"), "suggested_edit")
# Category        ID       Place1 Place2 suggested_edit
# [1,] "abc-cba bac"   "123321" "bac"  "abc"  "bac, abc"    
# [2,] "adb- bac bad"  "213241" "N/A"  "bac"  "bac"         
# [3,] "bdl- bdc bdd"  "613251" "N/A"  "N/A"  ""            
# [4,] "ajk- bcd dcx"  "613251" "ddd"  "bcd"  "bcd"         
# [5,] "abc - bdd fcl" "776445" "trf"  "fss"  ""            
# [6,] "abc - bnc vcc" "767544" "vcc"  "qap"  "vcc"
```